# better database design to save large employee details in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am developing HR&Payroll system. I have to store employee details,employee details contains following data,

- basic details
- personal information
- passport information
- visa information
- labor card information
- emirate id information
- driving license details
- insurance details

I have created employee table and I allocated basic details and personal information.
[image]

My doubt is,for other details such as passport,visa,labor etc. should i create separate table for each item or include employees tables itself?
Or is there any other better method?

Comment: Does everyone have a passport?  Need a visa?  Have a drivers license?  Generally, if "not many" have some thing, put it in another table with fewer rows and plan on doing `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: yes.. am using new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the information in your table is liable to change over time (work_sites, grades_id etc.) you may consider keeping these in a separate table keyed by dates, as you may need to answer ("Where was bill working last January?") type of questions.

I would also check your security/privacy requirements, depending on how strict they are it may be a good idea to store passport numbers etc. in a separate more highly restricted table.

Comment: yea.. I am following separate tables for other details and I should think about first paragraph of your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping everything in the same table will make data entry and indexing easier. However, if you plan to use multiple tables then you can use `id` as a common attribute among the various tables. Please note that while grouping of information into multiple tables might seem an organized way, it increases the information retrieval complexity. More or less, everything depends upon the objectives of the project and usage patterns.

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen It really depends on the usage scenario. In this case, you can do away with a single table but as **James Anderson** says `it may be a good idea to store passport numbers etc. in a separate more highly restricted table`.